# validate text field and number

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

forms.py

```
class PhoneinfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    pname = forms.CharField(required=True)
    pnumber = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    gname = forms.CharField(required=False)
    gnumber = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Phone_info
        fields = ['pname','pnumber','gname','gnumber']

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        pname = cleaned_data.get("pname")
        pnumber = cleaned_data.get("pnumber")
        gname = cleaned_data.get("gname")
        gnumber = cleaned_data.get("gnumber")

        if 'pname' and 'pnumber' not in cleaned_data: 
            raise forms.ValidationError
        if 'gname' and 'gnumber' not in cleaned_data: 
            raise forms.ValidationError

        return cleaned_data
```

I am trying to validate name and number. In my case, `pname` and `pnumber` are one set and mandatory field, that i achieved my giving `required=True`.

2nd thing is `gname` and `gnumber` are not mandatory, but if `gnumber` is entered then it is taking blank to `gname` (if nothing enteredin gname it is accepting) that should not happen. If number is entered it should not accept without name or vice versa.

My code is not working for 2nd choice, how to validate this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me were i commited mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several bad things in your code:

1) When using `forms.ModelForm` it is not needed to declare fields in a form, if corresponding model fields have same constraints. From question example, if in model `Phone_info` corresponding fields have same `blank` attributes as form's `required`, it is not needed to declare fields again in a modelform.

2) As `pname` and `pnumber` are required, you don't need to check manually that they are filled. It is already done by `ModelForm`. So this is odd and must be removed:

```
if 'pname' and 'pnumber' not in cleaned_data: 
    raise forms.ValidationError
```

3) This line will **not** do what expected:

```
if 'gname' and 'gnumber' not in cleaned_data
```

It will first check condition `'gnumber' not in cleaned_data`. The result will be the boolean (True/False). And then condition `if 'gname' and False/True` will be applied.

What you want is:

```
gname = self.cleaned_data.get("gname", None)
gnumber = self.cleaned_data.get("gnumber", None)
if gname and gnumber is None:
    raise forms.ValidationError("gnumber must be filled")
if gnumber is not None and not gname:
    raise forms.ValidationError("gname must be filled")
```

4) As you've mentiond in p.3, `forms.ValidationError` must be initialized when raised:

```
raise forms.ValidationError("Error message")
```

**So result code**:

```
class PhoneinfoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # delete these fields, if they are the same, as in Phone_info
    pname = forms.CharField(required=True)
    pnumber = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    gname = forms.CharField(required=False)
    gnumber = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Phone_info
        fields = ['pname', 'pnumber', 'gname', 'gnumber']

    def clean(self):
        gname = self.cleaned_data.get("gname", None)
        gnumber = self.cleaned_data.get("gnumber", None)
        if gname and gnumber is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError("gnumber must be filled")
        if gnumber is not None and not gname:
            raise forms.ValidationError("gname must be filled")

        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Your explanation for the answer is very understandable..Thanks stalk

Comment: You are welcome. Updated to cover case, when gnumber is entered as 0. It is better to check in that case, that `gnumber is None`